# Fabric8 exec statuscode always 1000

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

I want to get the status code of my command executed in a container with Fabric8 Java Kubernetes client.

Here is the script located in my container:

```
echo Bye Bye
exit 1
```

When I run the script with CLI or NodeJS Client I am able to get the output status code

Here is an example taken from fabric8 repository:

```
package org.package;

import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.ExecListener;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.ExecWatch;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class OtherMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    String podName = "my-pod";
    String namespace = "my-namespace";

    try (
        KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
        ExecWatch watch = newExecWatch(client, namespace, podName)) {
      Thread.sleep(10 * 1000L);
    }
  }

  private static ExecWatch newExecWatch(KubernetesClient client, String namespace, String podName) {
    return client.pods()
        .inNamespace(namespace)
        .withName(podName)
        .readingInput(System.in)
        .writingOutput(System.out)
        .writingError(System.err)
        .withTTY()
        .usingListener(new SimpleListener())
        .exec("sh", "test.sh");
  }

  private static class SimpleListener implements ExecListener {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Response response) {
      System.out.println("The shell will remain open for 10 seconds.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t, Response response) {
      System.err.println("shell barfed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
      System.out.println("The shell will now close.");
    }
  }
}
```

However when looking at the output it seems that everything went ok. Is there a way to get the output status code ?

Comment: I think Fabric8 don't support this at the moment, could you please create an issue on Fabric8 Github repository?  https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by using the `wri` method:

Can use the `.writingErrorChannel` and parse the response:

```
{
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "command terminated with non-zero exit code: exit status 1",
    "reason": "NonZeroExitCode",
    "details": {
        "causes": [
            {
                "reason": "ExitCode",
                "message": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Type is: `io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Status`

Answer (score 0):

Since 6.x versions of Fabric8 Kubernetes Client, a new `exitCode()` method has been added to `ExecWatch` interface which returns a `CompletableFuture<Integer>`, so now you should be able to get exit code like this:

```java
ExecWatch execWatch = client.pods().inNamespace("default").withName("example-pod")
    .writingOutput(System.out)
    .writingError(System.out)
    .exec("/bin/ping", "goo");

// ...

int exitCode = execWatch.exitCode().get();
```